# I am trying to dynamically pull all <h3> elements from xhtml file and put them in a selection list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I am trying to dynamically pull all h3 elements from xhtml file and display them in a selection list. I have created the selection list but my code is not retrieving the h3 elements. I am very new to dynamic html and feel completely lost here. Any help would be great!

Here is a small clip of the xhtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- 
   New Perspectives on HTML, XHTML and DHTML 4th Edition
   Tutorial 16
   Case Problem 4

   The Tempest
   Author: Collin Klopstein
   Date: December 15, 2013  

   Filename:         tempest.htm
   Supporting files: bio_out.jpg, globe_out.jpg, plays.css, plays_out.jpg,
                     scene.js, son_out.jpg, strat_out.jpg
-->

<title>The Tempest, Act V, Scene 1</title>
<link href="plays.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="scene.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="linklist">
   <img src="plays_out.jpg"  alt="The Plays" />
   <img src="son_out.jpg"  alt="The Sonnets" />
   <img src="bio_out.jpg" alt="Biography" />
   <img src="globe_out.jpg" alt="The Globe" />
   <img src="strat_out.jpg" alt="Stratford" />
</div>
<div id="title"><img src="tempest.jpg" alt="The Tempest" /></div>
<div id="actList"><table><tr>
   <td>ACT I</td><td>ACT II</td><td>ACT III</td>
   <td>ACT IV</td><td>ACT V</td>
</tr></table></div>

<div id="characterList"></div>


<div id="sceneIntro">
<h2>Lines from Act V, Scene 1</h2>
</div>

<div id="scene">
<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><i>Enter PROSPERO in his magic robes, and ARIEL</i></blockquote>
<blockquote>Now does my project gather to a head:<br />
My charms crack not; my spirits obey; and time<br />
Goes upright with his carriage. How's the day?
</blockquote>

<h3>ARIEL</h3>
<blockquote>On the sixth hour; at which time, my lord,<br />
You said our work should cease.
</blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote>I did say so,<br />
When first I raised the tempest. Say, my spirit,<br/>
How fares the king and's followers?
</blockquote>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the JavaScript File:

```
/*
   New Perspectives on HTML, XHTML, and DHTML 4th Edition
   Tutorial 16
   Case Problem 4

   Author: Collin Klopstein  
   Date: December 15, 2013    

   Filename: scene.js


   Function List:
   uniqueElemText(elemName)
      Returns the unique content from HTML tags with the
      tag name elemName. The list is sorted in alphabetical
      ordered and returned as an array.

*/



function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
   if (object.attachEvent)
       object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
   else if (object.addEventListener)
       object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}

addEvent(window, "load", createListBox, false);//calls createListBox() when page loads

function uniqueElemText(elemName) {
   elems = document.getElementsByTagName(elemName);
   elemsArray = new Array();

   for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) elemsArray[i]=elems[i].innerHTML;  
   elemsArray.sort();
   for (i=0; i<elemsArray.length-1; i++) {
      if (elemsArray[i]==elemsArray[i+1]) {
         elemsArray.splice(i+1,1);
         i--;
      }
   }
   return elemsArray;
}

var characters = new Array ("h3");
var sourceDoc; // document on which the selection list is based

function createListBox() {
    var cList = document.getElementById("characterList");
    cList.innerHTML = "<p>Show Only Lines By:</p>";
    var cSelect = document.createElement("select");//creates selection list
    cList.appendChild(cSelect);//appends the selection list element to the cList element

    sourceDoc = document.getElementById("scene");

    uniqueElemText(sourceDoc, cSelect);//generate selection list
}

function levelNum(node) {
    for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        if (node.nodeName == characters[i]) 
            return i;
    }//node is a character
    return -1;//if node is not a character
}

function createOptions(object, option) {
    for (var n = object.firstChild; n != null; n = n.nextSibling) {
    //loops through all of the nodes within object

        var nodeLevel = levelNum(n);
        if (nodeLevel != -1) {
        //node represents a character

            var selectOption = document.createElement("option");//creates "option" element
            selectOption.innerHTML = n.innerHTML;
            option.appendChild(selectOption);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you write this code or get it from somewhere? If it someone else's code then you need to ask them for help...

Comment: Your `levelNum` function definition can be replaced entirely with `return character.indexOf(node.nodeName);`.

Comment: This is a homework assignment. The addEvent() and uniqueElemText() in the js file, the entire html file was written and provided as well. My assignment is to dynamically create a selection list which gives the h3 elements as its options. As the user selects an option, the page will display the blockquotes that follow the selected option. I'm sorry for the confusion, I just don't know where to begin with this.

Comment: Now that I have the h3 elements displayed, how would I call the uniqueElemText()? This function was provided for me to alphabetically sort the options in the selection list

Comment: The provided script is very ordinary. In the *addEvent* function, the test for *addEventListener* should be before the one for *attachEvent*. The value of *object* should be set to `null` to avoid circular references. The *uniqueElemText* function should be using *textContent/innerText*, not *innerHTML*, and so on.

Comment: Ah, so it isn't XHTML at all! Then why do you insist on referring to it as XHTML? Stop that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

The addEvent / onload logic doesn't seem to work, you can e.g. just put a call to `createListBox()` at the end of your script to fix this.

The check for an "H3" node is case sensitive, it works if you add `.toLowerCase()`. I.e. in function `levelNum()`, use this line:

```
if (node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == characters[i])
```

See also http://jsfiddle.net/Nzx9m.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `getElementsByTagName` to get the H3 elements and `indexOf` to test for unique values?

e.g. your function could look like this;

```
function createOptions(object, option) {
    var h3Tags=object.getElementsByTagName("h3");

    for(var i=0;i<h3Tags.length;i++){
        var h3Tag=h3Tags[i],
            val=h3Tag.innerHTML,
            selectOption = document.createElement("option");

        selectOption.innerHTML = val;
        if(characters.indexOf(val)==-1) {
            characters.push(val);
            option.appendChild(selectOption);
        }  
    }
}
```

see this fiddle for a working example (it doesn't do the last part, i.e. show only lines from the selected character) ... http://jsfiddle.net/dTdV4/